# Як одним словом назвати людину, що не має спадку?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

В англійській мові цьому терміну відповідає слово "portionless", - тобто той(та), у кого немає матеріальних статків, що дісталися від батьків.

Мала припущення, що слово використовується у юридичній термінології. Але знайома юристка сказала, що є термін "спадкоємець", а протилежного нема. Є варіант "безспадкоємець", але це неологізм. "Особа, що не має спадку" - задовго.

Comment: Добрий день. Дякую за питання. У наших правилах щодо того, [як мають виглядати хороші питання](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/240), є один пункт, на який хочу звернути вашу увагу: "В цілому, вітаються питання зі «спробою дослідження». Ваше запитання не зобов'язане бути складним, у нас має бути комфортно як новачкам, так і тим, хто глибоко вивчає мову — але, у будь-якому випадку, поясніть, з якими саме проблемами ви стикнулись при спробі вирішити питання самотужки." Ще раз дякую і сподіваюсь на подальшу співпрацю.

Comment: інший варіант неолоґізму: "безспадченко"

Comment: "Скільки можна було судити про людину, заковану у бойові обладунки, новий боєць був трохи вищий середнього зросту й здавався швидше тендітним, ніж кремезним. На ньому був сталевий панцир із багатою золотою насічкою; герб на його щиті зображував молодий дуб, вирваний із коренем; під ним був напис іспанською мовою: "Desdichado", що означає "Позбавлений спадщини". - Переклад "Айвенго" Вальтера Скотта українською https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/world/printit.php?tid=591&page=15.

Comment: Правда portionless та desinherited (у разі Айвенго) це різне - приклад з https://www.yourdictionary.com/portionless: "Returning home, he was disinherited by his father's will, for his marriage with Cornelia (Neeltje) Simons, a portionless gentlewoman".

Comment: Було б добре додати речення чи два контексту. Тоді можна було б точніше відповісти. Бо вже майже назбиралося інформації на відповідь.

Comment: А для чого використовувати одне слово замість двох? По своїй суті спадкоємець - теж два слова: спадок ємець. ймити спадок. Як не крутіть. а не вийде використати одне слово для дії і об'єкту дії. Потрібно просто підібрати правильно назву дії для нового випадку. Якщо відповісти на запитання "чому особа не має спадку?", то можливо можна підібрати назву дії для правильно слова. Тобто потрібно розкрити тему людини без спадку та причини відсутності спадку.

Comment: @P.Vowk, _безспадько_ :).

Answer (score 2):

Підсумовуючи коментарі й додаючи трішки від себе:

1. У словниках я знайшов лише один прикметник, який самостійно передає значення слова portionless. Отже, словник [linguisto](http://linguisto.epizy.com/dict/en.php):

> portionless *adj*
>
> що не має посагу (приданого) (про наречену), **безпосажна**
>   portionless daughters – безпосажні (дочки)
>   юр. що не має частки спадщини

Тож якщо потрібно сказати про дівчину без посагу — можна казати **безпосажна**.

2. Варіанти неолоґізмів для передачі portionless одним українським словом:

   - безспадько
   - безспадченко
   - безспадковий
   - безспадкоємець
3. Не відповідь на питання, але варіанти перекладу кількома словами:

   - особа, що не має спадку
   - [він/вона/вони] [був/була/були] без спадку
   - [він/вона/вони] [не мав/мала/мали] спадку

Comment: *безспадкоємець* більше схоже на того, у кого нема спадкоємця.